# How to create folder with trailing dot (.) in .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, ntfs, create-directory

I need to create folders with trailing dots (.) using C#. Here is my code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("d:\\MyCorp Inc.");
```

But the folder is created without the final dot. Is there a solution?

I am using .NET Framework 4.5/C#. My file system is NTFS, on Windows 8.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's not a limitation of C# nor .NET, but rather of OS you're using. Try it for yourself in explorer.

Comment: VIsual studio throws exceptions, you shouldn't do it but you can with cmd:
mkdir \\?\d:\MyCorp Inc.

and you'll notice you can't delete it so:
rmdir \\?\d:\MyCorp Inc.

Comment: "Why would you want to do that?" I have many customers that name their folders according to company name, for example "Some Corp Ltd.", these names often contain trailing dots. I can not store  names anywhere else, I do not have database and I can not create extra files, this is the requirement.

Comment: If that is a **requirement** then you are **required** to not use Windows. Knowing that, is it a **requirement** or is it merely *nice to have*?

Comment: i have updated my Answer check it out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775867/how-to-create-folder-with-trailing-dot-in-net-c/15776058#15776058

Comment: @EricLippert  or not, windows will let you do it.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: The *file system* might let you do it, but it is a really, really bad idea to make a directory that you then cannot reliably use from the *shell*. That will not delight users, it will confuse them.

Comment: @EricLippert  I agree, its a bad idea,  kind of like Metro is a bad idea, but people still run with it anyways and horrify their users.

Comment: @EricLippert we are not using the shell, we have UI that supports all characters including trailing dots.

Comment: @ITHitWebDAV: Who is this "we"? I'm talking about your customers, who have every expectation that they can use the shell to browse their entire hard disk. And all of their administrators, who have expectations that every backup, anti-virus, and other admin tools at their disposal will be able to analyze every directory. Are you going to test every one of those tools to make sure that they interact well with your product?  Don't *mitigate* bad practices, *avoid them in the first place*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateDirectory(@"\\?\c:\temp\MyCorp Inc.", IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

And refer to *[You cannot delete a file or a folder on an NTFS file system volume](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=320081)*.

Comment: Sorry! Thrown: "Illegal characters in path." win7 , 4.0

Comment: had to bypass .NET and go straight to the windows API as the API was doing extra validation.  Tested the code on my machine! :)

Comment: anyway in win7 this is also not doing well ,playing for some time with i found a tricky way , i have updated it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775867/how-to-create-folder-with-trailing-dot-in-net-c/15776058#15776058

Comment: is it accessible via explorer ?

Comment: @IOIOMAD  you can see it, but you can't use it from explorer

Comment: Sorry about my bad English , that i mean  not doing well ,what about my solution?

Comment: @IOIOMAD  your solution is a workaround,  it will work, but I'd either drop the requirement in that case or have the convention of .dot  if it ends with a . or something like that

Comment: how do you create a file that ends with (.)

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft clearly states that this is something that should not be done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Answer (score 5):

That is not a limitation of .NET, but of the [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) API. Try to create one in a command shell:

```
c:\drop>mkdir test.

c:\drop>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C0F3-338B

 Directory of c:\drop

2013-04-02  17:54    <DIR>          .
2013-04-02  17:54    <DIR>          ..
2013-04-02  17:54    <DIR>          test
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) for naming reccomendations. To quote:

> •Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period.
>   Although the underlying file system may support such names, the
>   Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable
>   to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example,
>   ".temp".

If you are really quite insistent on using a trailing dot, use `\\?\C:\path.`.

```
c:\drop>mkdir \\?\c:\drop\test2.

c:\drop>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C0F3-338B

 Directory of c:\drop

2013-04-02  17:58    <DIR>          .
2013-04-02  17:58    <DIR>          ..
2013-04-02  17:54    <DIR>          test
2013-04-02  17:58    <DIR>          test2.
```

---

**Edit:** The requirement as listed in the contents is that no additional files are created, so don't use a file. You can create a "name" stream on the directory and store data there. See the following for an example:

```
c:\drop>mkdir "Example Company Name"
c:\drop>notepad "Example Company Name:name.txt"
c:\drop>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C0F3-338B

 Directory of c:\drop

2013-04-02  18:25    <DIR>          .
2013-04-02  18:25    <DIR>          ..
2013-04-02  18:25    <DIR>          Example Company Name
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  77,336,379,392 bytes free
c:\drop>dir "Example Company Name"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C0F3-338B

 Directory of c:\drop\Example Company Name

2013-04-02  18:25    <DIR>          .
2013-04-02  18:25    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  77,336,313,856 bytes free
```

Or in .NET:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string companyName = "Example Company?*, Inc.";

        //Example Company Inc
        var sanitizedName = sanitize(companyName);

        //Create the directory
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sanitizedName);

        //Create the name store
        var nameStreamPath = sanitizedName + ":Name";
        writeFileContent(companyName, nameStreamPath);

        //Try to return the name
        Console.WriteLine(getFileContent(nameStreamPath));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string getFileContent(string path)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(
            // we have to call CreateFile directly to avoid overzealous path validation
            NativeMethods.CreateFileOrFail(path, false), FileAccess.Read)))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    private static void writeFileContent(string companyName, string path)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(
            // We have to call CreateFile directly to avoid overzealous path validation
            NativeMethods.CreateFileOrFail(path, true), FileAccess.Write)))
        {
            sw.Write(companyName);
        }
    }

    private static string sanitize(string path)
    {
        char[] newPath = new char[path.Length];
        int newPathLoc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(path[i]) || char.IsDigit(path[i]))
            {
                newPath[newPathLoc] = path[i];
                newPathLoc++;
            }
        }
        return new string(newPath, 0, newPathLoc);
    }
}

class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string fileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess fileAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare fileShare,
        IntPtr securityAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flags,
        IntPtr template);

    public static SafeFileHandle CreateFileOrFail(string path, bool write)
    {
        var handle = CreateFile(path,
            write ? FileAccess.Write : FileAccess.Read,
            write ? FileShare.None : FileShare.Read,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            write ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Open,
            FileAttributes.Normal,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        if (handle.IsInvalid)
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

        return handle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

**I have noticed two things!**

**1) Your requirement:**

> I have many customers that name their folders according to company
>   name, for example "Some Corp Ltd.", these names often contain trailing
>   dots. I can not store names anywhere else, I do not have database and
>   I can not create extra files, this is the requirement.

**2) You haven't got an answer**

My suggestion is to add an extra character at the end of directory name, which will be hidden to normal view, but still exist! Which makes us happy!

**Try this**

> ***You have to append a special character at the end of the directory name***

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory
                    (@"D:\Sync.inc." + (char)(128));
```

> **Note:(char)(128) to (char)(158) may help**

**Try a blast!**

```
for (int i = 128; i <= 158; i++)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory
        (@"D:\Sync.inc." + (char)(i));
}
```

Anyway as from MS:

> If the dot is at the end of the name, Windows will ignore the dot(s)
>   by default.
>
> Have a look at
>   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/84978c71-8203-404b-94cf-b05b14be99db/

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to do this manually in Windows Explorer even Explorer does not allow the trailing dot and removes it for you.

I imagine this is a limitation of Windows itself owing to a period at the end usually signifying a file extension.

At this time I would say it is not possible.