# Why Path.GetDirectoryName() removes the trailing dot in directory name?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Path.GetDirectoryName("/folder/subfolder./file.txt");
```

I expected the result to be `\folder\subfolder.`, but it is `\folder\subfolder` (without the dot). Why is the trailing dot removed?

**Edit**: it seems that you're not allowed to create such a folder in Windows. But take a look at this fiddle, it seems that in .net 4.5 the dot is included? https://dotnetfiddle.net/mq0OhR

Comment: Because MS-DOS, and extensions. It didn't used to be possible to even have directory names like that, and by default, on Windows, it's *still* not possible to create a directory like that by conventional means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx Microsoft says the following in the *Naming Conventions* part:

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Maybe thats the cause / reason the dot gets removed.

Comment: @ClaudiuConstantin no you cant, just confirmed, it removes the trailing dot automatically

Comment: Yup, I was wrong the first time, I had the impression that it worked, but it didn't

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775867/how-to-create-folder-with-trailing-dot-in-net-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET 4.6.1 or earlier? This was changed and works correctly in 4.7 and later

Answer (score 0):

In windows, it is not allowed to have period (.) as last character of directory name.

**MSDN** says

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

So .net assumes this behavior and removes it by default